# T value vs T-stat

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology

I've seen this term "t value" floating around, but I never understood what it is. Is it just a different way to say "t-stat," which is analogous to a Z-score, but for a t-distribution instead of a gaussian?

Comment: Let’s say I have a sample size of 36 and find there to be a mean of 2 and a standard deviation of 6. How would you calculate the t-value, t-stat, and p-value?

Comment: @Dave I don't you think you can calculate a p-value because you don't know the population mean, so you can't calculate the Z-score and hence p value?

Comment: @Dave I think you can compute the t statistic using 
$$
t = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{s/\sqrt{n}}
$$

where $s$ is the sample SD and $\mu$ is the population mean, which we don't know.

Comment: Let’s suppose we’re testing $H_0: \mu=0$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 0$.

Comment: Then the t stat is $t = \frac{2 - 0}{2/6} = 6$. Oh, I think the t-value is analogous to the p-value but for t-distribution? And T statistic is analogous to the Z-score

Comment: We call it a p-value no matter the distribution. As you go further in statistics, you’ll see p-values computed from chi-squared distribution, F distributions, and others. There’s not a new name for each distribution. // I would say that t-value and t-stat are just about synonyms. The one place where they might not be is if you look up a critical value in a reference table, where I’d call it a t-value and reserve “t-stat” for something calculated from data.

Comment: @Dave But then, what is a t-value?

Comment: @Dave Is the standard deviation of 6 you gave the sample SD, and not the unbiased estimate of the population SD? If so, then I think I can calculate the unbiased estimate of the population SD as $\hat{\sigma} = s \cdot \sqrt{n} / \sqrt{n-1}$. And then I think I can use this to compute a Z-score and p-value.

Comment: I meant for $6$ to be calculated from the data, in which case you would not use a z-score. There is no general formula for an unbiased estimator of standard deviation, by the way. (My first post on Cross Validated was about how the square root of the unbiased estimator for variance is (amazingly) biased for standard deviation.)

Comment: @Dave Oh I didn't know that. It seems dividing by $n-1$ gives an unbiased estimator of the population variance, but if you take the square root of that, you end up getting a bias estimator estimator of the population SD.

Comment: @Dave I'm still confused on the difference between a t value vs. t stat. Are you implying that they are different when you asked me to calculate each one?

Comment: See my earlier comment; they’re basically synonyms. I asked you to calculate each to see what you thought each term meant.

Comment: @Dave Oh sorry about that. For some reason, when I first read it I didn't see that part.

Comment: An opinion-based question. Here's my opinion: 'Test statistic' is the standard terminology for observed value used to for t, chi-squared,  etc tests.  In R, one can append `$stat` to a test procedure to show only the test statistic or `$p.val` to show only the P-value. When doing a t test it's natural to say 't-statistic'. and colloquially sometimes 't-value' instead (preferably not in writing). But never OK to say 't-value' in place of 'P-value'.

Comment: @BruceET Ah I see. There's also the "T-Score." Is that synonymous with t value/t-stat?

Comment: No, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-score#T-score

Comment: It almost seems an elaborate conspiracy to confuse students.

Comment: would you cite an example for  t - value and its calculation.

Answer (score 2):

When you assume that your test statistic (or loosely speaking the signal/noise ratio) follows a standard normal distribution, you could calculate z-scores instead of t-values. This could be the case if you sampled the entire population, or when you have access to a very large sample size.

On the other hand, when your sample size is small and hence the expected uncertainty in your estimates is likely larger, the t-distribution is more appropriate because it allows for more probability in the tails (fatter tails) when calculating the p-values from it. With a sample size of larger than 30, the t-distribution looks very much like the standard normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Definition).

As for t-value and t-statistic, I'd don't see a problem to use them interchangeably. The sample mean is also called a *statistic* but can also be labeled a *value*. What's important is that **sample statistics** (sample mean, sample standard deviation, t-value, z-scores) allow you to make inferences about the underlying population parameters.

Note however, that there is also something called the *T-Score*, which should not be confused with the *t-statistic* or *t-value*. From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score#T-score)

> In educational assessment, T-score is a standard score Z shifted and scaled to have a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 10. In bone density measurements, the T-score is the standard score of the measurement compared to the population of healthy 30-year-old adults.

Comment: I presume t-value is cited for T-score!

Comment: In a comment to the question you mentioned the T-score which on some readings is what the OP is trying to ask about, although not perhaps very clearly. Would it be better to mention that in your answer too? I know it is quite distinct from Student's T of course.

Comment: @mdewey thank you for comment! Yes I agree and added it to the answer.